# GetChartElement returns wrong chart series

Tags: excel, vba

I have an EXCEL chart plot containing lines and points.  I use `MouseUp/GetChartElement` to determine which series the user has alt-left clicked.  The `Chart_MouseUp` code is based on the code that Jon Peltier kindly posted on his website :

```
Private Sub Chart_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)

    Dim elementId As Long
    Dim arg1 As Long
    Dim arg2 As Long
    
    Dim xlSer As Series
    
    With ActiveChart
        .GetChartElement X, Y, elementId, arg1, arg2
        If elementId = xlSeries Then
            If Button = xlPrimaryButton And Shift = 4 Then
                Set xlSer = .SeriesCollection(arg1)
                MsgBox "User clicked series " & xlSer.Name
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that the series returned by the code is offset by 1: for example, if I click on series #6 then the code says I have clicked series #7.  There don't appear to be any hidden series on the chart (I checked by looping over `Chart.SeriesCollection`) so I am rather baffled.  Would appreciate any comments or thoughts ... thanks in advance

Comment: What does `Debug.Print ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.count` return in Immediate Window, against what you think that the last series is?

Comment: it prints 8 - which is the number of series shown on the plot

Comment: And if you click the last one what the function does return?

Comment: `Runtime error '1004' - parameter not valid`.  In debug mode, the error is caused by `arg1` being equal to 9 which is 1 more than `SeriesCollection.Count`

Comment: Does this happen on all your charts you tried? If yes, you simple adapt the function to return `Set xlSer = .SeriesCollection(arg1 - 1)`... Even if it has no meaning, since the SeriesCollections starts from 1. But this will be a way/workaround  to use it as you need... :)

Comment: No - just this one particular chart.  I did think about your suggestion but it doesn't apply in all cases and I was hoping to find the root cause before applying a short term fix

Comment: Can you share the workbook in discussion? Pn a transfer site...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219753/discussion-between-petgriffin-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 0):

As FaneDuru pointed out, one of the series was hidden (`SeriesCollection.Format.Line.Visible = False`) so that it was included in the overall series count (presumably maintained by Excel somewhere) but excluded from `SeriesCollection.Count`.  Deleting the hidden series solved the problem